# Flutter: sending data back to a file to display an event in calendar

Tags: flutter, events, calendar, flutter-dependencies

I am unable to figure out where I'm going wrong here. I intend to send data back after pressing the button on this file (`add_event_view.dart`) to `calendar_view.dart` so that the calendar view can build that event in the calendar. However, when I click on the button no event is created or displayed.

`add_event_view.dart` below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/flutter_colorpicker.dart';

class EventCreator extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventCreator({super.key});

  @override
  State<EventCreator> createState() => _EventCreatorState();
}

class _EventCreatorState extends State<EventCreator> {
  late final TextEditingController _title;
  late final TextEditingController _dateController;
  late final TextEditingController _description;
  late final TextEditingController _startTimeController;
  late final TextEditingController _endTimeController;
  late Color selectedColor = Colors.blue;
  late DateTime pickedDate;
  late DateTime _startTimeSelected;
  late DateTime _endTimeSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _title = TextEditingController();
    _dateController = TextEditingController();
    _description = TextEditingController();
    _startTimeController = TextEditingController();
    _endTimeController = TextEditingController();
    _startTimeSelected = DateTime.now();
    _endTimeSelected = DateTime.now();
    pickedDate = DateTime.now();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _title.dispose();
    _description.dispose();
    _dateController.dispose();
    _startTimeController.dispose();
    _endTimeController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate() async {
    DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(2999),
    );

    if (picked != null) {
      setState(() {
        _dateController.text = picked.toString().split(" ")[0];
        pickedDate = picked;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _selectStartTime() async {
    TimeOfDay? picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (picked != null) {
      setState(() {
        _startTimeController.text =
            MaterialLocalizations.of(context).formatTimeOfDay(picked);
        _startTimeSelected = pickedDate.add(
          Duration(
            hours: picked.hour,
            minutes: picked.minute,
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _selectEndTime() async {
    TimeOfDay? picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (picked != null) {
      setState(() {
        _endTimeController.text =
            MaterialLocalizations.of(context).formatTimeOfDay(picked);
        _endTimeSelected = pickedDate.add(
          Duration(
            hours: picked.hour,
            minutes: picked.minute,
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  void _openColorPicker() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Pick a Color'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ColorPicker(
              pickerColor: selectedColor,
              onColorChanged: (color) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedColor = color;
                });
              },
              pickerAreaHeightPercent: 0.8,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Create New Event"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _title,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                    autocorrect: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Title",
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(144, 71, 60, 60)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _dateController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Date",
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(144, 71, 60, 60)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    readOnly: true,
                    onTap: () {
                      _selectDate();
                    },
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          subtitle: TextFormField(
                            controller: _startTimeController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Start Time",
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            readOnly: true,
                            onTap: () {
                              _selectStartTime();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          subtitle: TextFormField(
                            controller: _endTimeController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "End Time",
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            readOnly: true,
                            onTap: () {
                              _selectEndTime();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _description,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    autocorrect: true,
                    minLines: 2,
                    maxLines: 5,
                    maxLength: 1000,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Description",
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(144, 71, 60, 60)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      counterText:
                          '${_description.text.length.toString()}/1000',
                      counterStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Event Color:",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            _openColorPicker();
                          },
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: selectedColor,
                            radius: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        // bool goBackOrNot = await _errorDisplayer();

                        List<Object> result = [
                          _title.text,
                          pickedDate,
                          _startTimeSelected,
                          _endTimeSelected,
                          _description.text,
                          selectedColor,
                        ];

                        Navigator.pop(context, result);
                      },
                      child: const Wrap(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.add_box_rounded),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Text("Add Event"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`calendar_view.dart` below:

```
import 'package:calendar_view/calendar_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CalendarView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalendarView({super.key});

  @override
  State<CalendarView> createState() => _CalendarViewState();
}

class _CalendarViewState extends State<CalendarView> {
  Widget currentBody = const MonthView();

  late String title;
  late String? description;
  late Color selectedColor;
  late DateTime pickedDate;
  late DateTime startTimeSelected;
  late DateTime endTimeSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    title = '';
    description = '';
    selectedColor = Colors.blue;
    pickedDate = DateTime.now();
    startTimeSelected = DateTime.now();
    endTimeSelected = DateTime.now();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    title = '';
    description = '';
    selectedColor = Colors.blue;
    pickedDate = DateTime.now();
    startTimeSelected = DateTime.now();
    endTimeSelected = DateTime.now();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void eventCreator(
    String title,
    DateTime date,
    DateTime startTime,
    DateTime endTime,
    String? desc,
    Color col,
  ) {
    // try {
    final event = CalendarEventData(
      description: desc ?? '',
      color: col,
      date: date,
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
      event: title,
      title: title,
    );

    CalendarControllerProvider.of(context).controller.add(event);
    // }

    //  catch (e) {
    //   returnSnackBar(
    //     context,
    //     "Error",
    //     e.toString(),
    //     ContentType.failure,
    //     const Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 1, 1),
    //   );
    // }
  }

  void eventRemover(CalendarEventData event) async {
    CalendarControllerProvider.of(context).controller.remove(event);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CalendarControllerProvider(
      controller: EventController(),
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: const Sidebar(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 137, 215),
          tooltip: 'Add',
          onPressed: () {
            _awaitReturnValuesFromEventCreator(context);
            final event = CalendarEventData(
              description: description ?? '',
              color: selectedColor,
              date: pickedDate,
              startTime: startTimeSelected,
              endTime: endTimeSelected,
              event: title,
              title: title,
            );

            CalendarControllerProvider.of(context).controller.add(event);
            // eventCreator(title, pickedDate, startTimeSelected, endTimeSelected,
            //     description, selectedColor);
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, size: 28),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Calendar"),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton<CalendarAction>(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                child: const Icon(Icons.view_agenda_rounded),
              ),
              onSelected: (value) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    switch (value) {
                      case CalendarAction.daily:
                        currentBody = const DayView();
                        break;
                      case CalendarAction.weekly:
                        currentBody = const WeekView();
                        break;
                      case CalendarAction.monthly:
                        currentBody = const MonthView();
                        break;
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                return const [
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: CalendarAction.daily,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.view_day),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Day',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: CalendarAction.weekly,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_week_rounded),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Week',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: CalendarAction.monthly,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_month_rounded),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Month',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ];
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: currentBody,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _awaitReturnValuesFromEventCreator(BuildContext context) async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const EventCreator(),
      ),
    );

    setState(() {
      title = result[0];
      pickedDate = result[1];
      startTimeSelected = result[2];
      endTimeSelected = result[3];
      description = result[4];
      selectedColor = result[5];
    });
  }
}
```

Kindly help! Thanks!

I tried removing and adding async to the functions that were involved in this.